# Forbid C preprocessor to change variable's name

Tags: c

Here is a code example

```
#define S 113

double some_func1()
{
    return S;
}

double some_funcN( float S )
{
    return S/0.1;
}
```

When I am trying to compile it I am getting this error:

**error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'**

I am wondering if it is possible to fix it without renaming the 'S' variable?

Comment: No, this is not possible. `#define S 113` will turn any `S` token into `113` and it doesn't do any context analysis to determine whether `S` is an existing variable in this or that case/function. To avoid such issues you should give your macro a more meaningful name that `S`.

Comment: Having a function to `return 113 / 0.1` (which the compiler would probably implement as `return 1130.0`) makes no sense anyway.

Comment: @Blaze: You are right. The only thing I came up with is #undef S. But that does look ugly.

Comment: But then what `S` will the first function use?

Comment: Solution: give macros and variables meaningful names.

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would severely diminish readability and maintainability of the code. The macro definition and the variable/parameter name serve different purposes and mean different things, they should not have the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token `S` will be replaced with `113` everyplace it appears.  You have a few options to fix this:

- Rename the parameter to `some_funcN`:

  ```
  double some_funcN( float n )
  {
     return n/0.1;
  }
  ```
- Undefine the constant before the function and redefine it after.  This has the disadvantage that `S` is defined in multiple places, so I wouldn't recommend it:

  ```
  #undef S
  double some_funcN( float S )
  {
     return S/0.1;
  }
  #define S 113
  ```
- Change `S` from a macro to a variable.  This allows variable scoping rules to take effect so that the function parameter `S` masks the definition of the variable `S` declared at file scope.

  ```
  const int S = 113;
  ```

Comment: *Undefine the constant ... This has the disadvantage that S is defined in multiple places*  If that were the path I were forced to take (legacy or third-party code conflicts, perhaps) I'd put the macro definition in a separate header file that held nothing but the macro defintion:  `#ifndef S #define S 113 #endif`.  At least that way there's only be one actual definition.